# проверка void delete с mockito

Tags: java, mockito

Имеем слой Model:

```
 Region(Long id, String name)
```

Репозиторный слой RegionRepository:

```
public void deleteById(Long id){
        regionRepository.deleteById(id);
```

Ума не приложу, как с помощью Mockito протестить удаляющий void метод, направьте в нужное русло, плиз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно проверить, что метод был вызван с определенными параметрами, попробуйте:

```
verify(repositoryMock, times(1)).deleteById(eq(12345)));
```

Comment: Я только начал изучать тестирование. Я до этого задавал через when(repositoryMock.getMethod()).thenReturn(methodResult);
А потом уже делал тестовый случай.

В данном случае с удалением я думал, что нужно так же задать, что объект Region удалится, при вызове методе и указании его id,  а потом как-то проверить это в тестовом случае?!

Comment: Если ваш репозиторий замокан, сам вызов метода замоканого объекта не должен кидать ексепшины.  Проблемы возникают обычно тогда, когда нужно обрабатывать полученные данные, потому что замоканый метод по умолчанию вернет null. С void методом переживать про это не нужно. 
Код из ответа нужно выполнять в концу вашего теста, тогда он проверит, что deleteById метод был действительно вызван. Если вам не нужно проверять параметры, можете заменить eq() на any().
Мокать void нужно будет, если вы хотите, чтоб метод бросил ексепшн: doThrow().when()

Comment: Имхо, смысл не в том, чтобы проверить "метод был вызван". Юнит-тест должен проверять, что "при вызове метода с такими входными параметрами **на выходе** получается вот такое состояние". Т.е. суть должна быть как раз в том, чтобы убедиться: удаление действительно отработало и записи с таким ID нет. 1) "До вызова - была, а после - нет". 2) "до вызова - не было, а после - тоже нет".

Comment: Верно, но в таком случае это уже больше интегрейшн тест, и мокито тут вообще не нужен. Можно, например, поднять h2 базу, зависит от деталей проекта уже